# CakePHP 2.0 RSS error (doesn't parse extension)

Tags: rss, migration, cakephp-2.0

I'm migrating one of my website from cake 1.3 to 2.0 rc1 and I have a problem with my rss feed.

When I call my feed with something like mydomain.com/mycontroller/index.rss I have an error :

Error: The action index.rss is not defined in controller MycontrollerController

Error: Create MycontrollerController::index.rss() in file: app/Controller/MycontrollerController.php.

```
<?php
class MycontrollerController extends AppController {
    function index.rss {

    }
}
...
?>
```

I didn't change anything since 1.3 (and rss were working), and I have the parseExtensions in my routes.php :

```
Router::parseExtensions('rss', 'xml');
```

I found nothing about it in the doc and google :(

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

The action in your controller shouldn't be named `index.rss`.

You should verify a few things:

• Are both the `TextHelper` and `RequestHandlerComponent` called in your controller?
• Have you created an index action with the following code?

```
if ($this->RequestHandler->isRss() ){
    $posts = $this->YourModel->find('all', array('limit' => 20, 'order' => 'Post.created DESC'));
    return $this->set(compact('posts'));
}
```

• Verify you have created a default.ctp in `/View/Layouts/rss/`

• Do the same for the RSS view in `/View/YOUR_CONTROLLER/rss/index.ctp`

Also, see the manual entry in [the Cake documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/rss.html).

If that doesn't solve the issue it could be related to URL rewriting with mod_rewrite. Do you have any other problems with URLs not being found?